# JavaScript Code From Browser Sources Tab - Beautification

Tags: javascript

I was attempting to solve the HackTheBox invite challenge, where I was directed to the inviteapi.min.js file in https://www.hackthebox.eu/invite.

The code starts with `eval(function(...`, and because I was using Google Chrome, I conveniently pressed the "{}" button, which formats the code to a readable form (what Chrome calls as pretty-print). However, despite this, I was still not able to obtain anything useful from the indented code.

One of the solutions which I found was to use a JavaScript beautifier, one of which I used is https://beautifier.io/.

To my surprise, after copying all of the original content in the inviteapi.min.js file, I was able to see how the verifyInviteCode and makeInviteCode functions worked respectively.

My questions are:

1) Am I right to say that the JavaScript code in the inviteapi.min.js file was "encoded" in a certain way, such that only JavaScript beautifiers could "decode" it such that its "true contents" behind it can be read?

2) If the answer to 1) is yes, why does such "encoding" occur? I understand that there could have been some design considerations - one of which I think is to shorten the amount of code?

3) Interestingly, after I used the pretty-print feature of Chrome on the .js file, I copied it to the beautifying site and it could not display the same results as when I copied the .js file contents without the pretty-print feature. I suppose that the pretty-print feature introduces new-line and space characters that broke the "encoding", and thus the beautifying site did not manage to successfully beautify the code?

Comment: It's a wargame and we can't help you ethically

Comment: and it's not an encoding, its name is [obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software))

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the requests made by beautifier.io, you'll see that one request is to

https://beautifier.io/js/lib/unpackers/p_a_c_k_e_r_unpacker.js

And the JS on hackthebox starts with

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){
```

So, if you examine the p_a_c_k_e_r_unpacker code, you can see how exactly it tries to detect if the passed code is minified using the "packed" method. It uses the following regular expression:

```
eval\(\(?function\(.*?(,0,\{\}\)\)|split\('\|'\)\)\))($|\n)
```

Which, for our purposes, can be simplified to:

```
eval\( <some matching logic> \))($|\n)
```

Which will match `eval(`, followed by some matching logic, followed by `)` and the end of a line (or the end of a string). The original minified code is matched by this pattern; the minified *and prettified* code is not matched by this pattern.

This regex *does depend* on the original code being *actually* minified - it does not expect the code to be indented, or over multiple lines, or anything like that, because that code *would not actually be minified*. The packer unpacker expects the passed code to *have been minified using Packer*, without being changed by anything else afterwards. In particular, the regex expects each eval chunk to end at the end of a line - but if you pass in code whose `eval` line spans across multiple lines, said code will not match.

Prettifying the code doesn't exactly *break* your ability to decode it - it'd be pretty simple to re-minify it and then call p_a_c_k_e_r_unpacker with the re-minified code.

It probably wouldn't be hard to tweak the regex pattern and the decoder to properly decode even prettified packer-minified code, but that's not what the unpacker author expected it to be used for, so that functionality was not built in, I would imagine.